# How prove this $\cos{x}+\cos{y}+\cos{z}=1$

Tags: trigonometry

**Question:**

> let $x,y,z\in R$ and such $x+y+z=\pi$,and such
>   $$\tan{\dfrac{y+z-x}{4}}+\tan{\dfrac{x+z-y}{4}}+\tan{\dfrac{x+y-z}{4}}=1$$
>   show that
>   $$\cos{x}+\cos{y}+\cos{z}=1$$

My idea: let $$x+y-z=a,x+z-y=b,y+z-x=c$$
then
$$a+b+c=\pi$$
and
$$\tan{\dfrac{a}{4}}+\tan{\dfrac{b}{4}}+\tan{\dfrac{c}{4}}=1$$
we only prove
$$\cos{\dfrac{b+c}{2}}+\cos{\dfrac{a+c}{2}}+\cos{\dfrac{a+b}{2}}=1$$
Use
$$\cos{\dfrac{\pi-x}{2}}=\sin{\dfrac{x}{2}}$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \sin{\dfrac{a}{2}}+\sin{\dfrac{b}{2}}+\sin{\dfrac{c}{2}}=1$$
let
$$\tan{\dfrac{a}{4}}=A,\tan{\dfrac{b}{4}}=B,\tan{\dfrac{\pi}{4}}=C$$
then
$$A+B+C=1$$
and use $$\sin{2x}=\dfrac{2\tan{x}}{1+\tan^2{x}}$$
so we only prove
$$\dfrac{2A}{1+A^2}+\dfrac{2B}{1+B^2}+\dfrac{2C}{1+C^2}=1$$

**other idea:let**
$$\dfrac{y+z-x}{4}=a,\dfrac{x+z-y}{4}=b,\dfrac{x+y-z}{4}=c$$
then we have
$$a+b+c=\dfrac{\pi}{4},\tan{a}+\tan{b}+\tan{c}=1$$
we only prove
$$\cos{(2(b+c)}+\cos{2(a+c)}+\cos{2(a+b)}=\sin{(2a)}+\sin{(2b)}+\sin{(2c)}=1$$
then I fell very ugly, can you some can help?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What were the reasons invoked for temporarily suspending your account?

Comment: maybe I do somewrong thing.sorry

Comment: @math110 The problem with your attempt is considering $\cos\dfrac{b+c}{2}$ as $\sin\dfrac{a}{2}$ which is not always true since $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$. I tried to help you using geometry approach by considering $x,y,z$ as the angles in the triangle but then I realized it is impossible because $x,y,z\notin\mathbb{Z}_+$.

Comment: why is not true?

Comment: @Tunk-Fey The relation $\cos(\pi/2-x)=\sin x$ holds for *any* value of $x$; it doesn't matter at all whether $x$ is the angle of a triangle.

Comment: @math110: I believed that you should use this identity; if $a+b+c=
\pi$ then $tan(a)+tan(b)+tan(c)=tan(a)tan(b)tan(c)$ In your case left hand side is equal to $1$.

Comment: @egreg My fault. I thought that would be only $\pi$.

Comment: "Then I fell very ugly". Don't. Everyone is beautiful in the inside.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Looking down at the positive octant , ( arrow tips are coordinate axes).

$x+y+z=\pi$  ( the cyan colored plane. )

$\cos{x}+\cos{y}+\cos{z}=1$ , ( the pink colored area. )

$\tan{\dfrac{y+z-x}{4}}+\tan{\dfrac{x+z-y}{4}}+\tan{\dfrac{x+y-z}{4}}=1$ , (the light gray colored area. )

I can see three solutions where the gray central area, surrounded by pink triangle meets the cyan plane.

Just a picture!

Comment: This picture is very  beautiful!

Comment: Indeed, but even such a _proof without words_ IMHO needs to be somewhat more verbose to be convincing ..

Comment: The equation: $\cos{x}+\cos{y}+\cos{z}=1$ is an infinite lattice of octahedra-like surfaces in space. Along the plane: $x + y + z = \pi$ I would concentrate my attention on the lines: $(t,\pi - t, 0)$, $(t,0,\pi - t)$ , and $(0,t,\pi - t)$ the conditions of the theoerm seem to hold. ( I am limiting myself to a description of the diagram, there may be more to prove, for example, translation along these three lines).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

An interesting view of the surface $ \cos x + \cos y + \cos z = 1 $ Three lines ( in red ) are added for clarity. We can see that even along the plane $ x + y + z = \pi $ we must add a network of lines to encompass the simple periodicity condition.

Answer (score 0):

Now,I have solution this problem:let $x,y,z\in R$ and such $x+y+z=\pi$,and
$$\tan{\dfrac{y+z-x}{4}}+\tan{\dfrac{x+z-y}{4}}+\tan{\dfrac{x+y-z}{4}}=1$$
show that
$$\cos{x}+\cos{y}+\cos{z}=1$$
$$\dfrac{y+z-x}{4}=a,\dfrac{x+z-y}{4}=b,\dfrac{x+y-z}{4}=c$$
we have
$$a+b+c=\dfrac{\pi}{4},\tan{a}+\tan{b}+\tan{c}=1$$
we only prove following
$$\cos{(2(b+c)}+\cos{2(a+c)}+\cos{2(a+b)}=\sin{(2a)}+\sin{(2b)}+\sin{(2c)}=1$$
since $$\tan{a}+\tan{b}+\tan{(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-a-b)}=1\Longrightarrow
\tan{a}+\tan{b}+\dfrac{1-\tan{(a+b)}}{1+\tan{(a+b)}}=1$$
$$\tan{a}+\tan{b}=\dfrac{2\tan{(a+b)}}{1+\tan{(a+b)}}$$
$$\Longrightarrow 1=\tan{a}+\tan{b}-\tan{a}\tan{b}$$
then
$$\sin{(a+b)}=\cos{(a-b)}$$
other hand we have 
\begin{align*}\sin{(2x)}+\sin{(2y)}+\sin{(2z)}&=2\sin{(x+y)}\cos{(x-y)}+1-2\sin^2{(x+y)}\\
&=2\sin{(x+y)}[\cos{(x-y)}-\sin{(x+y)}]+1\\
&=1
\end{align*}